# Auto-replace unicode \uxxxx characters in a text file with their utf-8 equivalents

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding

I've been given a huge properties file created in eclipse with ISO-8859-1 encoding, and all Greek characters in it are in Unicode format (i.e.: \u03bc\u03af\u03b1\u0020\u03bc\u03ad\u03c1\u03b1). It works fine, but I want the actual file to be human readable.

I converted the file to utf-8, but the characters remained as they were. Is there a way to automatically convert the contents of the file to utf-8 either from inside eclipse, or via an external tool?

Comment: What is going to use this properties file? Depending on which API the program calls to load the properties it may not be able to deal with UTF-8.

Comment: I've already added some new values in utf-8 and they also work fine, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [**AnyEdit Tools**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) plugin:

When installed, in the editor hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to select all the text containing ASCII and Unicode formatted characters), **right-click** and choose ***Convert > From Unicode Notation***.